# How do I tell if Im on Server 2003 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Just wondering how I tell I was sure I installed a VM with R2 but it doesnt say.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you look?  Right-click My Computer and get Properties.  It should give you the precise edition.

Comment: +1 Because I don't think we should forget to check the basics first.

Comment: Correct and confirmed on one of my 2K3 R2 boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Click start then run and type WINVER and hit enter.  It will tell you if it is R2.

Answer (score 1):

Start -> Run -> winver.exe from within Windows or click on the Summary tab in the vSphere client to see what you selected (but not necessarily what is installed)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a programmatic way to do it, you can use PowerShell and WMI to get the same string as in My Computer -> Properties...

```
powershell -command "$str = (gwmi win32_operatingsystem).name; $str -like '*R2*'"
```

(True if R2, false if not R2)